# Create CMake/CPack <Library>Config.cmake for shared library

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

I have the simplest possible c-library which builds and is packed using the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project (libfoo C)

add_library(foo SHARED impl.c)
target_link_libraries(foo)
install(TARGETS foo LIBRARY DESTINATION lib/)
install(FILES public_header.h DESTINATION include/libfoo)

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "TGZ")
include(CPack)
```

Working example is located here: https://github.com/bjarkef/cmake-simple/tree/master/libfoo

I execute `mkdir -p build; (cd build/; cmake ../; make all package;)` to build a `.tar.gz` package with the compiled shared library along with its public header file. This is all working fine.

**Now I wish to modify the `CMakeLists.txt` to create the `FooConfig.cmake` and `FooConfigVersion.cmake` files needed for CMake `find_package` in a different project to find the foo library. How do I do this?**

I have discovered I should used the [CMakePackageConfigHelpers](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html): `configure_package_config_file` and `write_basic_package_version_file`, and I should create a `FooLibraryConfig.cmake.in` file. However I cannot figure out how to put it all together.

Note that it is important the the resulting `.cmake` files only contains relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

I have cmake module included in the top level CmakeList.txt:

```
# Generate and install package config files
include(PackageConfigInstall)
```

Within the generic PackageConfigInstall.cmake file, the config files are created from the cmake.in files, and installed.  This module can be reused for other packages.

```
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

# Generate package config cmake files
set(${PACKAGE_NAME}_LIBRARY_NAME ${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX}${PACKAGE_NAME}${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})

configure_package_config_file(${PACKAGE_NAME}-config.cmake.in 
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PACKAGE_NAME}-config.cmake 
   INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR}/${PACKAGE_NAME}
   PATH_VARS LIB_INSTALL_DIR INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR APP_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR )

configure_file(${PACKAGE_NAME}-config-version.cmake.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PACKAGE_NAME}-config-version.cmake @ONLY)

# Install package config cmake files
install(
    FILES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PACKAGE_NAME}-config.cmake
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PACKAGE_NAME}-config-version.cmake
    DESTINATION
        ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR}/${PACKAGE_NAME}
    COMPONENT
        devel
)
```

You'll need a package file for your library, such as your_lib-config.cmake.in, which will become your_lib-config.cmake.  This will contain the include and library variables that can be used.

```
get_filename_component(YOUR_LIB_CMAKE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)

# flag required by CMakePackageConfigHelpers
@PACKAGE_INIT@

set_and_check(YOUR_LIB_INCLUDE_DIR @PACKAGE_YOUR_LIB_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR@/hal)
set_and_check(YOUR_LIB_LIBRARY @PACKAGE_LIB_INSTALL_DIR@/@CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX@@PROJECT_NAME_LIB@@CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX@)
set_and_check(YOUR_LIB_LIBRARIES @PACKAGE_LIB_INSTALL_DIR@/@CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX@@PROJECT_NAME_LIB@@CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX@)
```

You'll also want a config-version.cmake.in file like this:

```
set(PACKAGE_VERSION @PACKAGE_VERSION@)

# Check whether the requested PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION is compatible
if("${PACKAGE_VERSION}" VERSION_LESS "${PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION}")
    set(PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE FALSE)
else()
    set(PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE TRUE)
    if ("${PACKAGE_VERSION}" VERSION_EQUAL "${PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION}")
        set(PACKAGE_VERSION_EXACT TRUE)
    endif()
endif()
```

There's quite a bit to the packaging scripts to get it all to work just right.  I went through a lot of trial and error to finally get something that works on different targets (both linux server and embedded target).  I might have left something out, so please just comment and I'll update answer.

Comment: I cannot try this within the bounty expiration time, so I have awarded you the bounty because of your thorough answer. I will accept your answer later when I have time to try it out myself. Thank you. :)