# <Package>Config.cmake for a library package

Tags: c++, cmake, deployment

We equipped a library package with a *Config.cmake file, following step 11 of the CMake tutorial.  Yet our downstream software fails to find the library.

Our package is called "formfactor" [https://jugit.fz-juelich.de/mlz/libformfactor].  It provides a shared library (libformfactor) and some header files.

Our downstream code uses

```
find_package(formfactor REQUIRED CONFIG)
message(STATUS "formfactor: found=${formfactor_FOUND}, include_dirs=${formfactor_INCLUDE_DIR}, "
    "lib=${formfactor_LIBRARY}, version=${formfactor_VERSION}")
```

to search for the library.  Alas, it prints

```
formfactor: found=1, include_dirs=/usr/local/include, lib=, version=0.1
```

That is, it does not find the library, yet fails to raise a fatal error though we said "REQUIRED".

Package "formfactor" contains all the following:

**`CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(formfactor VERSION 0.1.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

if(NOT DEFINED BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build as shared library" ON)
endif()
option(WERROR "Treat warnings as errors" OFF)

add_subdirectory(ff)

install(EXPORT formfactorTargets
  FILE formfactorTargets.cmake
  DESTINATION cmake
)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
configure_package_config_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Config.cmake.in
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/formfactorConfig.cmake"
    INSTALL_DESTINATION cmake
    NO_SET_AND_CHECK_MACRO
    NO_CHECK_REQUIRED_COMPONENTS_MACRO
    )

write_basic_package_version_file(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/formfactorConfigVersion.cmake"
    VERSION "${formfactor_VERSION_MAJOR}.${formfactor_VERSION_MINOR}"
    COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
    )

install(FILES
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/formfactorConfig.cmake
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/formfactorConfigVersion.cmake
    DESTINATION cmake)

export(EXPORT formfactorTargets
  FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/formfactorTargets.cmake
)
```

**`Config.cmake.in`:**

```
set(formfactor_INCLUDE_DIR @CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@/include)
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/formfactorTargets.cmake)
```

**`ff/CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
set(lib formfactor)
set(${lib}_LIBRARY ${lib} PARENT_SCOPE)

file(GLOB src_files *.cpp)
set(api_files Polyhedron.h PolyhedralTopology.h PolyhedralComponents.h)

add_library(${lib} ${src_files})

target_include_directories(${lib}
    PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    )

set_target_properties(
    ${lib} PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME ${lib}
    VERSION ${formfactor_VERSION}
    SOVERSION ${formfactor_VERSION_MAJOR})

install(
    TARGETS ${lib}
    EXPORT formfactorTargets
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)

install(
    FILES ${api_files}
    DESTINATION include/ff)
```

Anything wrong? Anything missing? Why else doesn't it work?

Disclosure:

- Cross-posting from https://discourse.cmake.org/t/find-package-config-mode-wont-find-library/4573.
- I have seen the related discussion [Create CMake/CPack <Library>Config.cmake for shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103110). Here I am interested in a solution that does all the automatic file generation recommended in the CMake tutorial.

Comment: Why do you expect that call to `find_package(formfactor)` will set `formfactor_LIBRARY` variable? Your script `Config.cmake.in` doesn't set it.

Comment: What else is the purpose of Step 11 in the CMake tutorial?

Comment: Anyway, I would be glad to do without the "EXPORT ..Targets" overhead. If only I knew how to set `formfactor_LIBRARY` in `Config.cmake.in`.

Comment: The "modern" usage of `find_package(formfactor)` is linking (using `target_link_libraries`) with `formfactor` **target** (which is created in your project via `add_library` call and installed). Exactly generated script `formfactorTargets.cmake` is responsible for creation of that target. Linkage with the target cares about include directories, libraries, and some other things. The "older" usage pattern of `find_package` is using `*_LIBRARY` and `*_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` variables. The script `formfactorTargets.cmake` doesn't create these variable, so they should be set in `Config.cmake.in`.

Comment: If you want to provide "older" usage patter in your `Config.cmake.in`, then you could `set(formfactor_LIBRARY formfactor)`. So, linking with `${formfactor_LIBRARY}` will actually link with the `formfactor` **target**.

Comment: Say we want to go for "modern" usage. Do you mean that everything is right in our formfactor configuration, the problem is just with how we use the formfactor target in downstream? What then do we need to change downstream to find the formfactor include directory and to link?

Comment: "What then do we need to change downstream to find the formfactor include directory and to link?" - As I said above, the downstream just needs to `target_link_libraries(<downstream_exe> PUBLIC formfactor)`. That command will add include directories, libraries and everything else.

Comment: I'll try immediately. One more little question please: For debugging, how would I print out the "target"? `${formfactor}` or ?

Comment: You cannot "print the target": The target consists from many properties, some of which becomes printable only at the end of configuration process. For debug you could build your project with `make V=1`, so you will see complete command lines used for compiling and linking your project. Looking into these command lines you could check e.g. include directories passed to the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script `formfactorTargets.cmake`, generated by CMake via

```
install(EXPORT formfactorTargets
  FILE formfactorTargets.cmake
  DESTINATION cmake
)
```

defines **only targets**, which has been added to the export set with that name (`formfactorTargets`).

Since you have added only a single library to it

```
set(lib formfactor)
...
install(
    TARGETS ${lib}
    EXPORT formfactorTargets
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
```

the script defines only a library **target** `formfactor`.

Linking with that target is the "modern" usage of `find_package` results:

```
# downstream
find_package(formfactor REQUIRED CONFIG)
target_link_libraries(<my executable> PUBLIC formfactor)
```

---

It is up to your `Config.cmake.in` script (which will be installed as `formfactorConfig.cmake`, that is read by the `find_package(formfactor)`) to provide additional information for your package and/or its additional usage.

E.g. you could set variables `formfactor_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `formfactor_LIBRARIES`
so a downstream could use your library via "old way", assuming variable `formfactor_INCLUDE_DIR` to contain include directories and variable `formfactor_LIBRARIES` to contain a library file(s) which are needed to link with:

```
find_package(formfactor REQUIRED CONFIG)
include_directories(${formfactor_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(my_exe <sources>)
target_link_libraries(my_exe PUBLIC ${formfactor_LIBRARIES})
```

It is quite difficult for you (as a package's developer) to provide absolute path to the library. But you could assign variable `formfactor_LIBRARIES` in a
way which "just works":

```
# Config.cmake.in

# Value of 'formfactor_INCLUDE_DIRS' is real: it contains the include directory.
set(formfactor_INCLUDE_DIRS @CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@/include)

# Value of 'formfactor_LIBRARIES' is fake: it doesn't contain a library path.
# But linking with ${formfactor_LIBRARIES} will work, as it will link
# to the **target**, and CMake will extract a library path from it.
set(formfactor_LIBRARIES formfactor)

# In any case we need to include the export script generated by CMake:
# exactly this script defines 'formfactor' target.
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/formfactorTargets.cmake)
```